# Laravel spatie/laravel-backup Digital Ocean spaces

Tags: php, laravel, backup, backups

i am using laravel-backup from spatie to backup my laravel application files and database and store them on a digital ocean space. 
this works just fine for me.

I have another digital ocean space, were uploaded user files gets stored to.

My question is. Do i need to backup the digital ocean space as well? or can one trust on them? does digital ocean backup spaces by themselves somehow?

here is the config file i am using to backup my stuff:

```
<?php

return [

    'backup' => [

        /*
         * The name of this application. You can use this name to monitor
         * the backups.
         */
        'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'laravel-backup'),

        'source' => [

            'files' => [

                /*
                 * The list of directories and files that will be included in the backup.
                 */
                'include' => [
                    base_path(),
                ],

                /*
                 * These directories and files will be excluded from the backup.
                 *
                 * Directories used by the backup process will automatically be excluded.
                 */
                'exclude' => [
                    base_path('vendor'),
                    base_path('node_modules'),
                ],

                /*
                 * Determines if symlinks should be followed.
                 */
                'follow_links' => false,
            ],

            /*
             * The names of the connections to the databases that should be backed up
             * MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite and Mongo databases are supported.
             *
             * The content of the database dump may be customized for each connection
             * by adding a 'dump' key to the connection settings in config/database.php.
             * E.g.
             * 'mysql' => [
             *       ...
             *      'dump' => [
             *           'excludeTables' => [
             *                'table_to_exclude_from_backup',
             *                'another_table_to_exclude'
             *            ]
             *       ]
             * ],
             *
             * For a complete list of available customization options, see https://github.com/spatie/db-dumper
             */
            'databases' => [
                'mysql',
            ],
        ],

        /*
         * The database dump can be compressed to decrease diskspace usage.
         *
         * Out of the box Laravel-backup supplies
         * Spatie\DbDumper\Compressors\GzipCompressor::class.
         *
         * You can also create custom compressor. More info on that here:
         * https://github.com/spatie/db-dumper#using-compression
         *
         * If you do not want any compressor at all, set it to null.
         */
        'database_dump_compressor' => null,

        'destination' => [

            /*
             * The filename prefix used for the backup zip file.
             */
            'filename_prefix' => '',

            /*
             * The disk names on which the backups will be stored.
             */
            'disks' => [
                'do_spaces_backup',
            ],
        ],

        /*
         * The directory where the temporary files will be stored.
         */
        'temporary_directory' => storage_path('app/backup-temp'),
    ],

    /*
     * You can get notified when specific events occur. Out of the box you can use 'mail' and 'slack'.
     * For Slack you need to install guzzlehttp/guzzle and laravel/slack-notification-channel.
     *
     * You can also use your own notification classes, just make sure the class is named after one of
     * the `Spatie\Backup\Events` classes.
     */
    'notifications' => [

        'notifications' => [
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\BackupHasFailed::class => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\UnhealthyBackupWasFound::class => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\CleanupHasFailed::class => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\BackupWasSuccessful::class => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\HealthyBackupWasFound::class => ['mail'],
            \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\CleanupWasSuccessful::class => ['mail'],
        ],

        /*
         * Here you can specify the notifiable to which the notifications should be sent. The default
         * notifiable will use the variables specified in this config file.
         */
        'notifiable' => \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifiable::class,

        'mail' => [
            'to' => 'your@email.com',
        ],

        'slack' => [
            'webhook_url' => '',

            /*
             * If this is set to null the default channel of the webhook will be used.
             */
            'channel' => null,

            'username' => null,

            'icon' => null,

        ],
    ],

    /*
     * Here you can specify which backups should be monitored.
     * If a backup does not meet the specified requirements the
     * UnHealthyBackupWasFound event will be fired.
     */
    'monitor_backups' => [
        [
            'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'laravel-backup'),
            'disks' => ['local'],
            'health_checks' => [
                \Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Monitor\HealthChecks\MaximumAgeInDays::class => 1,
                \Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Monitor\HealthChecks\MaximumStorageInMegabytes::class => 5000,
            ],
        ],

        /*
        [
            'name' => 'name of the second app',
            'disks' => ['local', 's3'],
            'health_checks' => [
                \Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Monitor\HealthChecks\MaximumAgeInDays::class => 1,
                \Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Monitor\HealthChecks\MaximumStorageInMegabytes::class => 5000,
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],

    'cleanup' => [
        /*
         * The strategy that will be used to cleanup old backups. The default strategy
         * will keep all backups for a certain amount of days. After that period only
         * a daily backup will be kept. After that period only weekly backups will
         * be kept and so on.
         *
         * No matter how you configure it the default strategy will never
         * delete the newest backup.
         */
        'strategy' => \Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Cleanup\Strategies\DefaultStrategy::class,

        'default_strategy' => [

            /*
             * The number of days for which backups must be kept.
             */
            'keep_all_backups_for_days' => 3,

            /*
             * The number of days for which daily backups must be kept.
             */
            'keep_daily_backups_for_days' => 5,

            /*
             * The number of weeks for which one weekly backup must be kept.
             */
            'keep_weekly_backups_for_weeks' => 4,

            /*
             * The number of months for which one monthly backup must be kept.
             */
            'keep_monthly_backups_for_months' => 3,

            /*
             * The number of years for which one yearly backup must be kept.
             */
            'keep_yearly_backups_for_years' => 2,

            /*
             * After cleaning up the backups remove the oldest backup until
             * this amount of megabytes has been reached.
             */
            'delete_oldest_backups_when_using_more_megabytes_than' => 5000,
        ],
    ],
];
```

How are you guys handling backing up your user files?

System Infos:

Laravel 5.8.28
MySQL 5.7
PHP 7.2

Comment: You'd need to read their terms and conditions to see how and if the handle backups for you, but it's always a good idea to backup across providers. I've read some horror [stories](https://twitter.com/w3Nicolas/status/1134529316904153089) where company accounts get suspended by a provider.

Comment: @user3676604 How did you get you DB backup to work, I keep getting exit code 127 with "mysqldump not found error" error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are counting on these backups for restoration after an incident, malware, database corruption, etc., best practice from a disaster recovery (DR) standpoint in the business world is to have your backup in an alternate location from your production server.  Or if you have them in the same location, (prod and database backup), then probably you should send another copy to another server outside the Digital Ocean chain.

As noted, it is also good practice to store data with different providers for the reasons noted in the horror stories link.  This level of redundancy is really up to you and your relationship with your client - no need for overkill if this is not mission critical to an SLA or agreement with that client.

If you are moving outside that DO chain, don't forget to keep data protection in transit in mind.  IE don't make another problem (unsafe storage of the non-DO backups) out of the first one :)

All of this depends on how strongly and carefully you want to keep data.  If it is for a client, you may wish to move it off of DO.  If it contains private client data, be extra careful to ensure privacy (transport and storage) as well.